# Unable to get ImageMagick version *** extconf.rb failed ***

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick

i've googled this error a couple of times and got instructions to install rMagick win-32 from their website. However the win32 versions looks depecrated and is made for Ruby 1.8.6 as for i have 1.9.3.

Can someone please help me install this gem? I really can't be arsed to do the imageMagick installing on my PC for this since the code will be moved to other PC's etc. a couple of times in the next few weeks (school assignment, you know how i goes). And with that it appears that imageMagick CAN be installed along with this gem(Which is by far the best option in my case). Nonetheless, i can't figure out this error since i'm a pretty big n00b when it comes to these things.

```
   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
    checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
    Ongeldige stationsspecificatie.
    Unable to get ImageMagick version
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
            --with-opt-dir
            --without-opt-dir
            --with-opt-include
            --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
            --with-opt-lib
            --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
            --with-make-prog
            --without-make-prog
            --srcdir=.
            --curdir
            --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby


    Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
    .1/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
    Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2
    .13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
    An error occured while installing rmagick (2.13.1), and Bundler cannot continue.

    Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I faced the same problem. After search, I found solution from here

http://www.waydotnet.com/2010/02/12/rmagick-on-ruby-1-9-1-i386-mingw32-work-d/

http://phosphor-escence.blogspot.in/2010/12/if-you-fail-install-rmagick-on-mingw.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to install dev packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev
```

Hope this helps :)